# I am trying to auto adjust input text box based on content. But if content is more the input box shifts towards label

Tags: html, css

I want input box to adjust towards right only for type text. I tried removing "float:right;" and using margin-left but then input box is not aligning properly. I expect input text box to adjust towards right when I type content.. Below is CSS implementation:

```
.input[type = "text"],.input[type = "number"]{
 float: right;
 width: 30%;`minimum width`
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 padding: 0.3em;
 }
```